# Module importing (C++) --- ERROR "module file mapping invalid"

Tags: c++, import, module, export, c++20

ImageLoader.cpp // ERROR:E3344 module file mapping for 'SafeReleaseM' is invalid

```
import  SafeReleaseM;
import <wincodec.h>;
import <d2d1.h>;

class ImageLoader{};
```

SafeReleaseM.ixx

```
export module SafeReleaseM;

export template <class T> void SafeRelease(T** type)
{
    if (*type)
    {
        (*type)->Release();
        *type = NULL;
    }
}
```

I've set the standard to the latest C++ standard and C standard, added my source folder to module dependency directory, enabled scanning for modules.

In my head, this is a very basic test of modules, am I doing something wrong? I'm new to S.O, so if i should add additional settings information, please do tell.

EDIT: I am using Visual Studio 2022 Community (msvc)

EDIT #2: In a separate project, a similar approach worked exporting a template function. Perhaps there is an issue with my project configuration.

Comment: What module is ImageLoader.cpp building? Because you can't import a module from a source file that is not *itself* a module. Also, what compiler and build tools are you using?

Comment: @NicolBolas Are you saying that "ImageLoader.cpp" itself **must be a module** to **import** "SafeReleaseM.ixx"? "ImageLoader" is a file that contains logic to load images. It imports "SafeReleaseM" in order to use the [SafeRelease] template function which safely releases pointers. ALSO, i am using msvc with VS 2022

Comment: Actually, no; I misread something in the standard.

Comment: Upon further testing of modules, I find that i get this when attempting to use the template function, but not an int/char/normal void :<

Comment: You should add the specific code which does and does not work to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Creating a new project** and pasting the same code in worked.

Not sure what gave Visual Studio file mapping issues, but what i did differently was in a new project, I created the files through the solution explorer window. - Error might've been dependency/configuration related. Or caused by an update.

Answer (score 0):

The following procedure worked for me.

1. Exit Visual Studio
2. Delete the x64 directory in the project directory.
3. Start Visual Studio
4. Reload solution and build.
5. Error disappeared for me.